# Need to show Video Recording screen in specific UIView instead of full viewcontroller issue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Can we able to load LIVE video recording in certain space instead of full viewcontroller?

[image]
Can you please help me out this query?

I searched a lot, but I was unable to figure it out this solution.

I found some reference: https://github.com/omergul/LLSimpleCamera

but here,it's showing full screen video recording.

Comment: **Can we able to load LIVE video recording in certain space instead of full viewcontroller? Yes** You have change `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` frame and position accordingly

Comment: Thank you @PrashantTukadiya, Let me try this

Comment: Check this -  https://github.com/wess/Glimpse

Comment: Thank you @sohanvanani.. Let me try this and then I will get back to you..

Answer (score 0):

here it is you can do it this way

```
            var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = yourView.layer.bounds
            yourView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
```